# How can I give alignment to title which is set using toolbar in xamarin forms?

Tags: forms, xamarin

How can I give alignment to title which is set using toolbar in xamarin forms?

By default it comes left side on screen I want to set in center of toolbar.

Comment: Hello, see this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Specifically I'd like to see what have you tried and what are your results.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see you've joined StackOverflow!

I'm going to be honest with you and say there is [no solution](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83025/how-do-i-align-toolbar-item-to-the-left) short of creating a **custom renderer** for this. That's coming straight from Xamarin creator John Miller.

> Unfortunately, this is not a feature of Xamarin.Forms ToolbarItems yet. You would have to solve this natively in a renderer with something custom.

Now, a custom renderer can be hard to create, especially for a beginner, but Microsoft has some very good [help pages here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Here's the basic layout of how to do it:

1. Create a subclass of the renderer class that renders the native control.
2. Override the method that renders the native control and write logic to customize the control. Often, the OnElementChanged method is used to render the native control, which is called when the corresponding Xamarin.Forms control is created.
3. Add an ExportRenderer attribute to the custom renderer class to specify that it will be used to render the Xamarin.Forms control. This attribute is used to register the custom renderer with Xamarin.Forms.

Hope this helps.